# AngularJS: Make filter change only view representation not object itself

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have following filter:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("common")
    .filter( "spacefilter", function() {
        return function( input ) {
                return input.replace(/_/g, " ");
            };
        }
    );
})();
```

in view i have following tag:

```
<label ng-repeat="(key,val) in $ctrl.consumption">
      {{key | spacefilter }}
      <input type="number" class="form-input" pattern="[0-9]+" ng-model="val" ng-change="$ctrl.updateValue(key, val)"/>
</label>
```

The problem is, for some reason, in `$ctrl.updateValue` I get filtered `key`, but I want original. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The filter does not mutate `key` value. Therefore you should not get filtered `key` in `updateValue` method. Maybe there are some lines of code that you forgot to write here!